# Keycloak-js: Adapter manually setting tokens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, keycloak, openid-connect

coming here for some much needed help. We have quite the unique scenario with authentication using keycloak. Our requirement is as follows:

- "Parital" authenticated flow, where the backend creates a keycloak user, and returns the `access_token`/`refresh_token` for that respected user to our react front-end (uses `keycloak-js`)
- Standard keycloak authenticated flow where the user authenticates via the keycloak login page and is returned to our application happily authenticated (this works fine and as expected!)

As you can imagine, point 1 is where our troubles are. Whenever I try to set the tokens manually for our keycloak instance and go to refresh the token, the call fails to keycloak because of a `400 bad request` this is due to the request payload being undefined, though the instance properties (`keycloak.accessToken`, `keycloak.refreshToken` are populated):

```
grant_type: refresh_token
refresh_token: undefined
client_id: frontend
```

For implementation visuals, I've used @dasniko [Niko Köbler Implementation](https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-reactjs-demo/blob/master/src/services/UserService.js) as a starting point, but I simply just added a setter for the tokens:

```
import kc from 'keycloak';

const doLogin = kc.login;

const initKeycloak = (onAuthenticatedCallback: () => void) => {
  kc.init({
    onLoad: 'check-sso',
    pkceMethod: 'S256',
    enableLogging: true,
  }).then((authenticated: boolean) => {
    if (!authenticated) {
      console.log('user is not authenticated..!');
    }
    onAuthenticatedCallback();
  });
};

const setTokens = (access: string, refresh: string): void => {
  kc.token = access;
  kc.refreshToken = refresh;
};

const doLogout = kc.logout;

const getToken = () => kc.token;

const isLoggedIn = () => !!kc.token;

const updateToken = (successCallback: () => void) =>
  kc.updateToken(5)
    .then(successCallback)
    .catch(doLogin);
```

I also have setup the token refresh implementation similarly:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config: any) => {
  if (AuthService.isLoggedIn()) {
    const cb = () => {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${AuthService.getToken()}`;
      return Promise.resolve(config);
    };
    return AuthService.updateToken(cb);
  }
  return config;
});
```

Has anyone had any success attempting the above? Setting the keycloak tokens manually and not having the user login via keycloak first?

Comment: You are trying to use SSO protocol without SSO - really? It is also not clear, where are you calling that "setter for the tokens"?

Comment: Yup, really! My bad, silentCheckSsoRedirectUri is defined but didn’t include it in the example above. Will edit. 
Set tokens is being set via a request response. On the move but will add the code snippet as well. 

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to set the tokens manually.

You probably have the app and the keycloak instance on different domains? The underlying issue is probably correlated to the CORS policy settings or third party cookies / Anti-Tracking Software blocking the keycloak cookie.

For testing you can try disabling your anti-ads/tracking software or using a different browser. If it work. E.g. firefox is likely to work  whereas chrome has stricter defaults.

To fix the actual issue make sure to

- use a proper PKCE flow implementation (and not implicit flow).
- have properly setup the CORS settings (clients > your client > Web origins)
- try using the same domain for keycloak and the client app
- Also it might be that you set a port for the keycloak instance which then becomes part of the URI and which could break the policy (e.g. when explicitely specifying port 80 or 443). You might need to remove the port configuration or also set the port in the app.

See here for more information:

- https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-cookies-issue-in-chrome-incognito-mode/8292/6
- https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak/issues/93